# Does it makes a difference to say whether he is rather than whether he isn't?

Tags: grammar

In other words, since the use of the word **whether**, automatically assume one thing in both ways (like he is or he isn't), does it matter or makes any significant difference to say it one way rather than the other?

The question popped up when I read sentences like it in a book.

An example is:

> I wonder whether he wasn't also right in telling me that I should always arrive on time.

Answer (score 1):

The phrases

> I wonder whether he was also right in telling me that I should always arrive on time.

and

> I wonder whether he wasn't also right in telling me that I should always arrive on time.

have in common the implicit idea that "he" was right about something else that came up earlier in the narrator's discussion. That's the effect of including *also* in each sentence. So the question becomes, does the sense of the sentence change at all if you use "wasn't" in place of "was"?

From a purely objective standpoint, I think, the answer is *no*: Both wordings describe the same thought process and lead to the same possibility that "he" may be right again.

On a subtle level, however, presenting the narrator's wondering thought with the verb "wasn't" implies (to me) that the narrator may once have thought that "he" was wrong about punctuality, but that the previous instance in which "he" was proved correct has led the narrator to reassess that earlier opinion. Using the negatively formed idiom "I wonder whether he wasn't also right" somehow imparts a sense of second-guessing to the narrator's thought that the straightforward "I wonder whether he was also right" does not. At any rate I detect a difference in how the two sentences are pitched, even though their objective meaning is essentially identical.

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence you give as an example it certainly *does* make a difference which way you state it.  For instance, these two sentences are not identical in meaning:

> I wonder whether he was right.
>   I wonder whether he wasn't right.

In other words, a person may wonder in one direction but not wonder (that is, not care) about the other direction.

Of course, idiomatically many people might say "wasn't" when they actually mean "was," and vice-versa.  This is somewhat similar to how people often say, "I could [instead of 'couldn't'] care less."

Comment: Do you mean the use of this idiom is limited to when whether is used?

Comment: In the last paragraph

Answer (score 0):

You can say it either way, as long as the rest of the sentence conveys your intention. I think the most significant point in using the word "whether" is whether (or not), "or not" is necessary. Indeed, it is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

To my somehow limited knowledge of English, ***whether*** introduces two ways of an alternative rather than just one, e.g.:

> Mary said to me: I wonder *whether* he was right telling me I should always wear my glasses when using a knife, *or whether* he *shouldn't rather* have taken care of himself not to fall out of the window, as it happened to him yesterday.

If you extract the two questions included in this statement, you get:

> Was he right telling me I should always wear my glasses when using a knife?
> Should he have taken care of himself not to fall out of the window?

These are yes-or-no questions, and given the practical and moral implications they present, detached from any point of view of the inquirer, both answers should be yes.

But in the original sentence, Mary isn't asking us to answer those questions but is telling us she's asking herself, and not only asking herself, but wondering, which implies more than just a shadow of a doubt; in fact, she felt somehow irritated by the remarks concerning her own safety by somebody who wasn't able to take care of himself. Thus, with "to wonder", the question or statement following it is always inverted:

> I wonder whether/if he was right = I think he wasn't right
>
> I wonder whether/if he shouldn't have taken care of himself = I think he should have taken care of himself.